# Is root layout getWidth() always equals to screen width

Tags: android, view, android-bitmap

I am using this code in `onCreate` method of activity to create a bitmap

```
final DisplayMetrics displayMetrics =  context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
int screenWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
String filePath = "image.png";
final Bitmap fullImage = getBitmapFromAsset(context.getApplicationContext(), filePath);
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
RectF src = new RectF(0, 0, fullImage.getWidth(), fullImage.getHeight());
RectF dst = new RectF(0, 0, screenWidth/8f, screenWidth/8f);
matrix.setRectToRect(src, dst, ScaleToFit.CENTER);
mImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(fullImage, 0, 0, fullImage.getWidth(), fullImage.getHeight(), matrix, true);
```

The width of the bitmap should take 1/8 of the parent layout (which is a linear layout with width match_parent, it is first/root layout). and I am always gonna use portrait mode (`android:screenOrientation="portrait"` in the manifest file). so I think the above code should always work and I tested it on a few devices and it works very well, but is there any possible case when this code might fail?

I know I can wait for the layout to be inflated and then use `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` on the parent layout, but I would prefer this if it's stable!

Answer (score 1):

This is fine. However, I would do that after the layout is inflated and in a background thread. Here's my two cents.

1. If the bitmap creation takes too much time, we should not do this in the `onCreate` function as this might induce ANR. You can check the [developer's doc](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr) here to learn about keeping your app responsive.
2. Also, I would be careful of the image size that you are trying to load in the memory. If the image is too large, you might end up having OOM (out-of-memory) issue in some devices where the available memory might not be sufficient to load the image in the memory.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, 
Actually, it is a chess game so images must be loaded before the activity starts to show the pieces in the right place and images are pretty small around 5Kb and a total of 12 images so maximum 60 kb so I think that memory shouldn't be a problem let's wait if any other SO user see any stability issue in this code, I think I should be ok with current code, thanks for your help:)